# How to send Multiple mail Using laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

i'm new to laravel, i need to send multiple emails using laravel it is possible ?

i'm try :-

```
 Mail::send('mail.Vehicle_request', compact('result_email'), function($message) use ($result_email) {
                    $message->to($result_email->email, $result_email->first_name . ' ' . $result_email->last_name)
                            ->subject('Vehicle Request');
                });
```

Thank You

Comment: mail using jobs is a more reliable way to send  multiple mails 
refer this - https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-send-mail-using-queue-in-laravel-57example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mailable and send mail to multiple recipients adding them in the loop. You can refer more in the documentation link.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail

```
foreach (['taylor@example.com', 'dries@example.com'] as $recipient) {
    Mail::to($recipient)->send(new OrderShipped($order));
}
```